# How to create a date for identity field

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

Using SQL Server

I want to make a date column for identity field....

Table1

```
Date_ (Identity Field)

20123
20124
20125
20125
....
....
18901
```

From the table1, max(date_) is 20125

so `20125` should be current date `05/23/2012` 'mm/dd/yyyy

From the table1, i want to make a date from max(date_) field to min(date_) field

Expected Output

```
Date_  Correct Date

20123 05/21/2012 
20124 05/22/2012
20125 05/23/2012
20125 05/23/2012
....  .....
....  .....
18901 02/18/2004  'Approximately
```

How to make a query for this

Need SQL Query Help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fail to understand why you need this and the value for `18901` does not seem correct. I would also be interested in the significance of the date [`1957-04-17`](http://www.canoe.ca/HockeyRocketRichardGallery/24.html).

```
select dateadd(day, Date_, '19570417')
```